# Webkit float and display

Tags: css, webkit, css-float, media-queries

I've run into a problem with Webkit browsers (Chrome/Safari), CSS3 Media Queries, `display` and `float` on my [site](http://oo.apphb.com). The default styling on my webpage is to float the element `nav` to the right and `display:inline-block`. When the window is resized to mobile size, Media Queries restyles it to: `float:none; display:block`. The problem arises when the browser is sized back up to normal: the navigation element appears dropped down about the amount of its height. Here's some pictures and markup:

Window Normal and Site Displayed Correctly: 
[image: Window Normal and Site Displayed Correctly:]

Window Mobile Sized, Site Displayed Correctly:
[image: Window Mobile Sized, Site Displayed Correctly]

Window Sized Back To Normal, Site Displayed Incorrectly:
[image]

Here's the normal styling for `nav` (and *yes* I'm going to move the IE7 stuff into a separate stylesheet...)

```
nav {
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1;
    margin-top:30px;
    *margin-top:-70px;
}
```

Here's the media query that restyles `nav`:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) 
{   
     header nav 
     {
         margin:0;
         float:none;
         display:block;
     }
}
```

So, is this a Webkit bug, or expected behavior? Am I doing something wrong, or is Webkit? If it *is* a bug, anybody know any good workarounds? The live site is [here](http://oo.apphb.com), let me know if I need to provide anymore info. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reduced it down to this: http://jsbin.com/opawal/

- Start with the window wider than `480px`.
- Make it smaller than `480px`.
- Make it larger than `480px`.
- The "jump" has happened - to make it obvious, hit F5.

It's a bug.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav {
    float: right;
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    nav {
        float: none;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>h2 element</h2>
<nav>nav element</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was afraid so. Thanks. Do you know of any potential workarounds?

Comment: Try to achieve the same visual layout, but either don't use `float: right` on `nav`, or don't use `display: inline-block` on `h1`/`h2`. Try inverting your use of `float` and `inline-block`. Or maybe `position: relative` on `header` and `position: absolute` on the child elements to position them will be viable. If you can't find something that works, let me know and I'll take another look.

Comment: @Thomas Shields: The fix works for me. `float: left` solved it quite cleanly, nice work.

Comment: Still fully reproducible :\