# Weird float rendering in Chrome when using media queries

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float, media-queries

I've built a simple responsive menu that's by default laid out vertically, but if the resolution is wider than 400px i lay it out horizontally.

Vertically I simply use `display: block` and for the horizontal version I do `float: left` on `:first-child` and `float: right` on `:last-child` (because I want them to reach the edges of the wrapper).

If you check the fiddle in a wide enough resolution you should see three red boxes laid out horizontally. Resize the iframe and they should change to a vertical layout. Now, here's my problem, when you resize the iframe back to the horizontal layout the `:last-child` menu item will not render correctly in Chrome Version 26.0.1410.63 under Ubuntu 12.10 (I haven't tried other versions of Chrome), it works as it should in Firefox though.

http://jsfiddle.net/G2h9U/

This seems like a Chrome bug to me, but has anyone experienced the same and is there a fix?

Comment: Yup, it's a bug. But really, who resizes browser window in real life? Exclude us, geeks :)

Comment: True, but changing orientation on a mobile device is common. Unsure whether this happens in mobile chrome though.

Comment: Happens on mobile Chrome as well, still not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a Chrome issue that's been out there for a while.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53166

Another Stacker with the same issue.

[Webkit float and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560629/webkit-float-and-display)

Comment: I guess we'll just have to wait for a fix then. Thanks