# div background and media query wont work on chrome, but does on firefox + edge + opera + smartphone

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries

Basically I made a small webpage with a couple of divs and a background image. The media query does not work when the window is resized to less than 500px wide. But does on firefox + opera + edge + explorer + smartphone.

I have Google Chrome    47.0.2526.80 (Official Build) m (32-bit)
My pc is 64 bit I'm currently downloading 64 bit to check if that's the problem.

Here is the pastebin pastebin.com/YgJv5MMA
Here is the screenshot  i.imgur.com/buTLjzp.png

UPDATE: I have failed to download 64 bit chrome. Anyways I have found previous questions that point to bugs in chrome when resizing windows and using media queries here [Weird float rendering in Chrome when using media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024837/weird-float-rendering-in-chrome-when-using-media-queries?rq=1) and here  [Weird float rendering in Chrome when using media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024837/weird-float-rendering-in-chrome-when-using-media-queries?rq=1) .

EDIT FOUND PROBLEM. Was linking the html and css files through dropbox. I took the two files and put them on my local desktop and now the media query works when the page is minimized to less than 500px width. So i guess i wont be using dropbox. Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly. Can you explain better. I created a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/fvz9nyyf/

Comment: The media query does not work when the window is resized to less than 500px wide. It works in that fiddle that you showed. But not when I launch that exact same code from notepad++.

Comment: Then this is not the reason why it doens't work. Do you have some additional code somewhere on the page?

Comment: Hey i checked out what you asked, and no there is no other code on the page. However i was linking the html and css files through dropbox. I took the two files and put them on my local desktop and now the media query works when the page is minimized to less than 500px width. So i guess i wont be using dropbox. Thanks for looking into this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i checked out what you asked, and no there is no other code on the page. However i was linking the html and css files through dropbox. I took the two files and put them on my local desktop and now the media query works when the page is minimized to less than 500px width. So i guess i wont be using dropbox. Thanks for looking into this for me.