# Media Queries and Floating/Breaking Spans

Tags: html, css, layout, media-queries

```
span {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    span {
        display: inline;
        float: right;
    }
}
```

`<p>Some text. <span>Some occasionally-floated text.</span></p>`

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Us62/), if the result window is larger than 500px both lines of text are on the same line.

When the window is resized smaller, the span breaks the line, but resizing the window larger again doesn't reverse the behavior. The line break remains and the span floats on the next line. <strike>Is this the correct behavior?</strike> And is there a way around it: a way that the span can become inline with the other text again?

**Update:** This is a bug in Webkit (and Blink?) https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53166

Comment: would you consider changing the order of elements in the markup?

Comment: Assuming you're testing in Chrome, could be similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560629/webkit-float-and-display

Comment: can you wrap the first bit of text too - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/7Us62/1/

Comment: @thirtydot you're right, it's the same issue. I'll update with a link to the bug tracker.

Comment: web-tiki or Pete,the goal is to have one element floated right when there's enough room, but on a new line (not floated) when there isn't. I'm not worried about what the markup is. I'm happy to give someone a correct answer.

Comment: Note that floating an element automatically turns it into a block regardless of what display value you give the same element. In your case, the `display: inline` style should have no effect. Not necessarily related to the bug, but just thought I'd point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @thirtydot in comment, this is a webkit bug, mor info in this question : [Webkit float and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560629/webkit-float-and-display)

To achieve the disired layout, you can do this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7Us62/5/)**

*HTML:*

```
<p><span class="left">Some text. </span><span class="right">Some occasionally-floated text.</span></p>
```

*CSS:*

```
.left{
    float:left;
}
.right {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .right {
        float: right;
        clear:none;
    }
}
```